# Running Spring app built with gradle and flyway on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, gradle, heroku, build.gradle

I have a problem deploying my Spring boot application with gradle on heroku. The project works with flyway on migrations and postgres as database, I'm trying to do the deploy, but heroku is complaining and giving the following log:

```
2022-01-11T16:08:15.174724+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.174  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.310829+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.310  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.458987+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.458  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.557556+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.557  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.660010+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.659  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.758015+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.757  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.926062+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.925  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:15.950385+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:15.950  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "018 - criarArquivos"
2022-01-11T16:08:16.100506+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.100  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.143832+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.143  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.162863+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.162  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "019 - criarArquivosProposta"
2022-01-11T16:08:16.294016+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.293  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.336561+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.336  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.362030+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.361  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "020 - criarArquivosEdital"
2022-01-11T16:08:16.469778+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.469  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.531438+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.531  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.551781+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.551  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "021 - criarArquivosUsuario"
2022-01-11T16:08:16.646818+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.646  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.717529+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.717  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor       : 0 rows affected
2022-01-11T16:08:16.737369+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.737  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 21 migrations to schema "public", now at version v021 (execution time 00:11.952s)
2022-01-11T16:08:16.974590+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:16.974  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-01-11T16:08:17.048129+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:17.047  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2022-01-11T16:08:17.275410+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:17.275  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-01-11T16:08:17.435786+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:17.435  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-01-11T16:08:20.352207+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:20.351  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-11T16:08:20.365827+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:20.365  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-11T16:08:20.556259+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:20.556  WARN 4 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-01-11T16:08:24.205506+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.205  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'arquivosController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'arquivosPropostasService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'arquivosPropostasService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'arquivos.propostas' in value "${arquivos.propostas}"
2022-01-11T16:08:24.220521+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.220  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-11T16:08:24.222658+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.222  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-01-11T16:08:24.255639+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.255  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-01-11T16:08:24.258455+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.258  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.285249+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.285  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2022-01-11T16:08:24.285251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-11T16:08:24.285253+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319226+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022-01-11 16:08:24.318 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319228+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319231+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'arquivosController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'arquivosPropostasService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'arquivosPropostasService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'arquivos.propostas' in value "${arquivos.propostas}"
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319239+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319239+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319240+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319241+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319242+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319242+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319243+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319246+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319246+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319246+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319247+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319247+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319247+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319248+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319248+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319248+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319249+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319249+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319250+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319250+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319250+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.sti.sigproj.SigprojApplication.main(SigprojApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319253+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312-heroku]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319253+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_312-heroku]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319258+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_312-heroku]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319259+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_312-heroku]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319259+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [sigproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319259+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) [sigproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319259+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [sigproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319259+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [sigproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319261+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'arquivosPropostasService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'arquivos.propostas' in value "${arquivos.propostas}"
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319261+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319261+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319262+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319262+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319262+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319263+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319263+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319263+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319264+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319264+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319264+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319265+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319266+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 28 common frames omitted
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319266+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'arquivos.propostas' in value "${arquivos.propostas}"
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319266+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319267+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319267+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319267+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319267+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319268+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319270+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319271+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319271+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319271+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319271+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319272+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319272+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 39 common frames omitted
2022-01-11T16:08:24.319272+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-11T16:08:24.514445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-11T16:08:24.655431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-11T16:08:25.702604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=api-sistemaderegistroatual.herokuapp.com request_id=7d4601b8-32fa-4a8a-b375-c03c3d194bf6 fwd="179.124.141.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-11T16:08:26.525942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=api-sistemaderegistroatual.herokuapp.com request_id=95fbafa2-4c6a-40c5-b6cb-4d0a1217eb39 fwd="179.124.141.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my current build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.5.2"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.sti.sigproj.SigprojApplication'
        )
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.7.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-spring:2.3.0'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.5.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation('com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'snakeyaml' }
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.22'
    testImplementation 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test:5.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2'
}

group = 'com.sti.sigproj'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'sigproj'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And here is the procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/sigproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
flyway:migrate
```

Here is the part heroku is complaining in the arquivosPropostaService.java:

```
@Value("${arquivos.propostas.doc-chefia-imediata}")
private String diretorioDocsChefiaImediata;
```

That leads to application.properties:

```
arquivos.propostas=/arquivos/propostas
arquivos.propostas.doc-chefia-imediata=/docs-chefia-imediata
```

The project contains maven and recently was changed to gradle. I think the problem is in the procfile and in build.gradle or maybe some lack in config vars, an old version of the project worked on maven, but the current version needs gradle.

Comment: Flyway is executed by Spring Boot, this doesn't change when using Maven or Gradle. So basically the `flyway:migrate` doesn't do anything. Without a full stacktrace this would be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I will change the question with the complete log.

Comment: Wow, I think its a problem with migrations, gonna reset de database to test.

Comment: did you by accident also upgrade some libraries? Like use a newer version of Flyway? Or accidentally edited the sql files (like changes line endings etc.?).

Comment: I changed the sql files because the project was not in use by anyone, so, for propose of organization, I organizated the sql files and reseted this Im my machine, but forgoted and don't know how to do that on heroku.

Comment: I reseted flyway and a new error appears.

Comment: I will change the question one more time.

Comment: Without baselining you cannot reset/change the sql as that will change the checksum and thus lead to errors. Your current error has nothing to do with flyway but with missing properties in your `application.properties` or your `application.properties` isn't read (wrong location?).